# precedence of local providers in directives and components

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I think the local provider for a directive is to provide services for its content children, for example:

```
//template in a module 
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>{{ item.price | myPipe }}</td>    
   </tr>
</table>
```

`myPipe` has a dependency of `MyService` in its contructor:

So if I define a directive as:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[myAttr]", 
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyDirective { }
```

and apply it as:

```
<table>
   <tr myAttr>
      <td>{{ item.price | myPipe }}</td>    
   </tr>
</table>
```

then `MyService` in `myPipe`'s constructor can be resolved.

But if there is a component also define `MyService` in its local providers and apply it as:

```
<myComponent>
   <tr myAttr>
      <td>{{ item.price | myPipe }}</td>    
   </tr>
</myComponent>
```

since both the `MyDirective` and `MyComponent` can provider the service for `myPipe`, so which one will `myPipe` choose, local provider of  `MyDirective` or `MyComponent`?

Comment: Good question on a very confusing topic. See my answer, which hopefully highlights the practical aspects of the problem in your specific case. Sadly, an in-depth explanation would be very difficult to write and would be on par with Angular's own documentation, which I encourage you to read: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components and https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection. Also, in case of similar uncertainties, one of the best things to do it try out the different scenarios, which is what I did - you can see exactly how it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Premise

Every Component in Angular gets its very own Injector context, which is used to provide Services (or, more generally, Injectables) to itself and its component tree.

### Short answer

Pipes seem to always use the Injector context of the Component whose template they are in (*empirically tested by me, citation needed*). So if you have a Component (let's call it `parentComponent`) with a template that looks like this:

```html
<myComponent>
   <tr myAttr>
      <td>{{ item.price | myPipe }}</td>    
   </tr>
</myComponent>
```

then `myPipe` will **not** get the Service instance from either `myComponent` or `myAttr`! So the direct answer to your question is **neither**!

Instead it will get the Service instance as used (*provided*) by the declaring Component (i.e. `parentComponent`).

### Short explanation

In terms of HTML structure it does indeed seem that `myPipe` is a child of both `myComponent` and `myAttr`. However, **in terms of Angular's hierarchy** `myPipe` is a child of `parentComponent` and so it gets its service provider there. Also, pipes, unlike Components, are not affected by content projection (use of `<ng-content>`).

### Also...

It seems that your understanding of how services are provided is not quite right. Here are some corrections of the statements that you made:

1. "[I]f I define a directive as (...) and apply it (...) then MyService in myPipe's constructor can be resolved" - not correct, as indicated in my answer.
2. "If there is a component also define MyService in its local providers (...) both the MyDirective and MyComponent can provider the service for myPipe" - not correct either, for the same reason.

### Finally

Components behave differently from pipes. They form component trees and Injector contexts change accordingly. So if in place of `myPipe` you had a `yetAnotherComponent`, it *would* in fact get MyService as provided by `myComponent` as opposed to `parentComponent`.

### Finally finally

If your directive provides a Service and you apply that Directive to a Component, that Component will get the Service as provided by the Directive! Unless, of course, it has registered a provider itself.